# Rails JSON auto include associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I must render some data with a lot of associations.

It look like this:

```
render :json => current_client.items.some_scopes.includes(:assoscitation1, :assoscitation2, :assoscitation3 => {:nested_assoscitation1 => :nested_assoscitation2}).to_json(
        :include => {:assoscitation2 => {:include => :type}, 
                     :assoscitation1 => {}, 
                     :assoscitation3 => {:include => 
                       {:product => {:include => :type}}
                      }
                    }
    )
```

AR includes is fine. I added it in scope. But specify all this associations in `to_json` method again makes me sad.
How can i remove this duplication?
Or maybe add presentrs level?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point (of ugliness in big hashes) I would recommend RABL.

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/

Answer (score 0):

RABL is awesome while AMS is also a good option:

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers